# Copy profile button needs clarification

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

As a casual user of mainly two stacks, I think of reputation as part of my profile. Therefore, the button to "Copy -Stack X- Profile to Related Accounts" is scary. Reputation on Stack A, 200. Rep on Stack B, 50. If I push copy, what happens to my reputation? Couldn't say. After searching through meta, I now know it's the biographic type fields get copied and reputation for the accounts is separate for each account.

My suggestion is to add text to the confirmation pop-up that says something like "Reputation is not affected by this copy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, maybe a link to the documentation you found for "copy" would be better.  It would sort this question out for people who are confused, and also give answers to similar confusions which might somehow arise.

This should be provided before the confirmation popup; a small link "(?)" next to the copy button would probably suffice.

p.s. Where was the documentation you found?

Comment: The "documentation" was a question (and answer) on meta. I searched around but couldn't find the post I saw. Sorry.